# Retrieve count value one by one

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want fetch data by referral count id:

```
foreach ($users as $user) {
    echo $referrals = $user->referrals_count."</br>";
    //output is $referrals=3
}
```

This above code retrieve count value of referral.

If user has three referral then it's  three.

What I am trying to get output is $referrals=3, its print 1, 2, 3, and if condition print like this.

```
foreach ($users as $key=>$user) {
    $referrals=$user->referrals_count."</br>";
    for ($i=1; $i<=$referrals; $i++) {
        $ref=$i < $referrals ? $i . ',' : $i;
        //Here is referral is 2
        if($ref==2 && $total=1500) {
            if($ref==1){
                echo  $payoutAmount= number_format(( 4.2*$total/100),2)."</br>";
            }
            if($ref==2){
                echo  $payoutAmount= number_format(( 3.2*$total/100),2)."</br>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `for ($i=1; $i<=$referrals; $i++) { echo $i < $referrals ? $i . ',' : $i; }`

Comment: Yes, what can I do

Comment: RiggsFolly@ Answer is  Great .. Can you chek edit question.. I am unable to implement this code with script

Comment: Bit confusing! $ref cannot be 1 if you are inside an `if $ref == 2` Not sure what you are trying to do here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200978/discussion-between-sanjay-yadav-and-riggsfolly).